# Where is the jar file (of java libries inside NSF) kept in a Domino server

Tags: lotus-notes

In Lotus notes, we can create Java libries inside the designer and call it in any Java agents.
Do any one know where the jar of there libries and agents are kept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Java library created from within Domino Designer is stored in a single "note" in the database NSF file. Within this note, the Java code is actually stored as multiple file attachments - a .java file and a (compiled) .class file. These are not exposed other than through the Java library editor in Domino Designer.

If you want/need to see more of the internal structure of how and where such design elements are stored, [NotesPeek](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24005686) is a great utility for examining the internals of any NSF.

Answer (score 3):

All code you write in Domino Designer or import into your database is stored in the database.  It's not stored on the file system in any other way.  So when you copy or replicate a database all the design elements, including your java code are copied / replicated just like all the other design elements (Forms, Views etc.)

Your code can reference external jars (i.e. using `include com.foo.bar.*`) as long as they are they are listed in the client and server's JavaUserClasses notes.ini setting or are in the Notes/jvm/lib/ext dir.

Answer (score 0):

OK.. there is a couple of things here.

Firstly, when you write some code into a java agent it is stored within the agent design element, that is, it's stored within the database, (ie the "nsf" file). It's not dropped onto the file system and is not accessible.

You can see the jar file within the design element, by looking at the properties of the agent design element in the notes designer. Even if you add jar's to the project and so forth they should be there as well. But it's not accessible from the file system.

Secondly, if you write java in eclipse like a servlet, or to be copy/pasted back into the domino designer, you need to have the notes jar files from the notes client added to your eclipse project so it will compile and have type ahead working for Domino objects.

There are in the Lotus Notes source directory, (usually C:\lotus\notes\data\domino\java directory NCSO.jar). Servlet jars are not available on the Notes client.

Look [here](http://blog.lotusnotes.be/domino/archive/2007-12-08-eclipse-agents.html) for eclipsed based development.

Ed's point about Notes Peek is a good one. Check it out.